# Multiple facebook app id for a single iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, fbsdkloginkit

Currently I am using `FBSDKLoginManager` with a Facebook app id to sign in via Facebook into my application. I have the required things in .plist file. Everything works fine.

[image]

But now I have to login in another section of my application with a different Facebook app id. How could I use different Facebook app id in a single application in various area.

Someone already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455219/how-can-i-use-multiple-facebook-app-ids-in-a-single-ios-application) previously. From the answer I found

> ```
> FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:@"AN_APP_ID"
>                                           permissions:nil
>                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceNone
>                                       urlSchemeSuffix:nil
>                                    tokenCacheStrategy:nil];
> [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
>     // do stuff here
> }];
> ```

But the answer does not work for me as `FBSession`is not available. Any idea? Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this tutorial that specifically addresses your problem in particular, and how to manage different environments in general: https://medium.com/slalom-engineering/ios-managing-multiple-environments-with-a-single-target-94cf823a6447

To go directly into what you want, search for "FacebookAppID" on that link.